# заменить часть слова js

Tags: javascript, replace

есть хтмл код

```
<tr id='rowIdHidden'>
    <td class='editable' id="Host-rowIdHidden"></td>
    <td class='editable' id="App-rowIdHidden"></td>
    <td class='editable' id="Comment-rowIdHidden"></td>
    <td class='editable' id="Disabled-rowIdHidden"></td>
    <td><a href="#" id='Delete-rowIdHidden' class="deleteRow">delete</td>
</tr>
```

в джава скрипте идет замена **только** первого вхождения "rowIdHidden" из-за того что все последующие являются чатью слова.

Как заменить лишь часть слова? Скорее всего нужно какое-то regex-выражение.

Но на практие мне его не удалось подобрать.

Comment: Думаю в итоге никто не понял что вам на что надо заменить и что вы конкретно хотите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы храните код html как строку то замену можно произвести, как вы правильно заметили, с помощью регулярного выражения.
Вот пример вашего случая (если я его правильно понял), при условии что переменная **string** инициализирована с нужным вам текстом:

```
string.replace(/rowIdHidden/g, 'чем заменить')
```

Comment: Пробовал, не работает. В таком случае не заменяет даже первое вхождение (полное, а не часть слова). В принципе для меня не играет роли как. Так что если возможно скопировать ДОМ елементы другим способом с заменой части слов в айдишниках -- я не против сделать это другими способами. Но ведь все равно прийдется делать замену части слова...

Comment: Можно полный код как вы это делаете? Трудно наугад определить что не так, так как код который я предложил я проверил перед публикацией.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/JOj7bx9.png

Comment: Прошу прощения, моя ошибка. Одну букву пропустил в названии переменной при последней правке. Все работает. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста! А я уж тут задумался что может быть не так...